# Querying a Global State Store in Kafka Streams throws a Null exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When creating a global KTable using the Processor API and the `addGlobalStore` function the resulting store populates OK. But subsequent attempts to iterate over the store's contents results in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                             at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.SerializedKeyValueIterator.next(SerializedKeyValueIterator.java:63)                                               at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.SerializedKeyValueIterator.next(SerializedKeyValueIterator.java:26)                                               at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore$MeteredKeyValueIterator.next(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:208)                                  at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore$MeteredKeyValueIterator.next(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:189)                                  at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore$CompositeKeyValueIterator.next(CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.java:155)            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore$CompositeKeyValueIterator.next(CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.java:113)            at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.DelegatingPeekingKeyValueIterator.hasNext(DelegatingPeekingKeyValueIterator.java:63)
```

This is from simple code that iterates over the store:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, StreamConfig> store = this.globalStreams.store("config-table",QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Config>keyValueStore());
final KeyValueIterator<String, Config> iteratble = store.all();
HashMap<String, Config> dynamicStreams = new HashMap<String,Config>();
while (iteratble.hasNext()) {
    final KeyValue<String, Config> next = iteratble.next();
    dynamicStreams.put(next.key, next.value);
}
iteratble.close();
```

Any access to the entries in that store causes that exception. The same topic works fine if I create the global state store using the `globalTable` function (so this is not a deserialization problem).  The state store also returns the number of rows successfully (so it *is* fully populated).

The Global State store is created as follows, this is using Kafka Streams 0.10.2.1.

```
KStreamBuilder globalBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
StateStoreSupplier<KeyValueStore<String, Config>> storeSupplier = Stores
    .create("config-table")
    .withKeys(Serdes.String())
    .withValues(configSerdes)
    .persistent()
    .build();

// a Processor that updates the store
ProcessorSupplier<String, Config> procSupplier = () -> new ConfigWorker();
globalBuilder.addGlobalStore(
    storeSupplier.get(), 
    "config-table-source", 
    new StringDeserializer(),
    configDeserializer, 
    "config", 
    "config-worker", 
    procSupplier)
    .buildGlobalStateTopology();

this.globalStreams = new KafkaStreams(
    globalBuilder, 
    this.getProperties());
globalStreams.start();
```

---

Edit:

- One problem was that the state store by default is logged and global KTables are not backed by a change log. So adding a `.disableLogging` to the state store creation fixed this.
- Another problem seemed to be in the call to `context.schedule` in the Processor's `init` function. This was throwing an invalidation operation exception. Removing this fixed the code, but I guess `punctuate` is now never called. It seems to work now - but it's not clear why I can't call `schedule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that forwarding in a global context is not allowed, as per this [code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1844bf2b2f4cdf5a8209d7ceccb6701fc7dcf768/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/GlobalProcessorContextImpl.java). So my global Processor just needs to process inbound updates only.